# Build fail for Asp.Net Core 3 (Blazor client side)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I've start to develop a web application with ASP.NET Core 3 and Blazor framework.
During few days/weeks, I could build my application. 
Since preview 5 announced, I couldn't build my application (with `dotnet build` command).
I've the next error:

```sh
C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(439,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "" -l    
-o "D:\Repos\IdeaStudio.Website.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\linker/" 
-x "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" 
-x "D:\Repos\IdeaStudio.Website.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\linker.descriptor.xml" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.browser\3.0.0-preview5-19227-01\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.0.0-preview5.19227.9\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.0.0-preview5.19227.9\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.0.0-preview5.19227.9\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.0.0-preview5.19227.9\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll" 
-a "C:\Users\a\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.6.0-preview5.19224.8\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" 
-a "D:\Repos\IdeaStudio.Website.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\IdeaStudio.Website.Client.dll"" exited with code 1. 
[D:\Repos\IdeaStudio.Website.Client\IdeaStudio.Website.Client.csproj]
```

My `csproj` looks like :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
      https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json;
      https://dotnet.myget.org/F/blazor-dev/api/v3/index.json;
    </RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I did not understand for several days until...

Comment: Which command did you run?

Comment: @MindSwipe dotnet build

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12916) GitHub issue for mono (the runtime for blazor) tracks this error code. Someone was able to fix it by adding `<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>` to the ProertyGroup tag in the csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe when I did the Visual Studio / .NET Core 3 preview 5

`dotnet cli` can't build an application with a csproj which contains `<TargetFramework>` and `<TargetFrameworks>` properties...

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12916) issue on the Mono GitHub is related.

Basically, as far as I understand it, somewhere in Mono the IL Linker fails and throws this cryptic error message. We can see hints to this in your error message.

As of now, michaelccote on GitHub solved the problem by adding the `<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>` element inside the `<PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>` tags of the .csproj file

Comment: Which .csproj-File? *.Server or *.Client?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Blazor WebAssembly, ASP.NET Core 3.1 please navigate to `yoursolution/yourproject.Client/` and edit `yourproject.Client.csproj`-File. Add the following line:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    [...]
    <BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
  </PropertyGroup>
  [...]
</Project>
```